# why no such directory "sensor_msgs"

Tags: ros, kinect, sensor-msgs, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone! I am using mit-ros-pkg "hand detection". I met a problem and then I checked the directory and files. I found that there should be a directory "sensor_msgs" while I do not I have. Help! Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34273/why-no-such-directory-%22sensor_msgs%22/) by [tan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2317/tan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2317/tan/) on 2012-05-18**:
thank you very much. that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, you should always provide an exact error message and which ROS version you are using (see [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29) for support guidelines).

I assume that the error is not because a missing directory but because you are missing the ros package sensor_msgs. To get it, install the stack common_msgs. If you are using ROS Fuerte, do

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-common-msgs
```

If you are using ROS Electric, do

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-common-msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1